# Lazy loading old messages with NSFetchedResultsController while doing realtime communication

Tags: ios, core-data, lazy-loading, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uirefreshcontrol

Consider a chat application scenario, where you have a very large group with 100,000+ messages and realtime communication.

Just like most chat applications, we want the latest messages to appear at the bottom i.e. new items are added at the bottom.

1. What's the best practice for using lazy loading with `NSFetchedResultsController`? Changing the fetch-request by increasing the `fetchLimit` doesn't seem like a good idea. Also, using an extra array instead of `fetchedObject` also doesn't seem like a very elegant or convenient solution either.
2. What's the best practice for showing latest messages at the bottom i.e. reversing the `UITableView` direction? Transform doesn't seem to be an elegant solution, or is it?

Looking for an elegant solution, that's working for people. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchLimit` doesn't work with `NSFetchedResultsController`.  To limit the controller you can do the following:

1. Do a single fetch with a fetchLimit=1 and a fetchOffset=BATCH_SIZE (where the batch size is something large, but not huge = ~200)
2. get the date of that message that you fetched
3. limit the fetchedResultsController to the date of that message.

Now you have a fetchedResultsController that is 200 messages.  Note that it may increase in size as long as it is open.

When a user scroll back you can do some similar adjusting of the `fetchedResultsController` by doing a fetch to figure out a correct date range.

For display the cells I have used the double-inverse method (apply a 180 rotation to the collectionView and a 180 rotation to every cell). It is not that elegant but it works and it is not as expensive as it first seems - the whole screen is already in an openGL layer behinds the scenes anyways.  There are a lot of little things that it caused (like the scrollIndicator being on the wrong side), but also a lot of little things that it fixed (like dealing with a chat with very few messages).  If I had to do it again I would make a custom layout, but I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss the double-inverse method.